# Error when installing Bootstrap with yarn in symfony Project

Tags: bootstrap-4, installation, yarnpkg, symfony-4.3

I'm try to install bootstrap in my symfony project (4) with yarn command.
"error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache"

i follow guide document for symfony. https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html

i've tried to clear cache, remove yarn dependencies from package.json, reinstall yarn, delete package.json et install again. i also try to give licence for my package.json with the command : "yarn licenses list"

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.28.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

when i try to use : "yarn add bootstrap@4 --dev", i get this error : "error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache"

warning messsage for each yarn command i execute : No licence field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `yarn cache clean`

I'm gonna go out on a limb and assume that by *clearing the cache* you removed `node_modules`, which is not the cache (I made the same mistake).

See answer here for more detail:

[Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172688/incorrect-integrity-when-fetching-from-the-cache)