# Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache

Tags: yarnpkg

When running `yarn add --dev jest`, I got *error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache*.

### Full output:

```sh
tests (master)$ yarn add --dev jest
yarn add v1.19.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I tried removed `node_modules`, re-ran `yarn install` and `yarn add --dev jest` to no avail.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

### `yarn cache clean`

To fix this, run:

```sh
yarn cache clean
yarn add --dev jest
```

From the [yarn cache documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/cache/):

> #### `yarn cache clean [<module_name...>]`
>
> Running this command will clear the global cache. It will be populated again the next time yarn or yarn install is run. Additionally, you can specify one or more packages that you want to clean.

You can also see where the cache is with `yarn cache dir`.

> #### `yarn cache dir`
>
> Running yarn cache dir will print out the path where yarn’s global cache is currently stored.

Comment: For global packages there is no equivalent to `yarn cache clean`. Manually removing `~/.cache/yarn` solved the 'incorrect integrity' error for me.

Comment: `yarn cache` commands are all about **global** cache. @imolit

Answer (score 5):

Yarn cache clean did not help. We must downgrading yarn version on the server.

It turns out that the problem is associated with the use of private packages.

[GitHub Yarnpkg - "Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache" #7584](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7584)

Comment: Specifically these instructions worked for me: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7584#issuecomment-536437423

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is working with heroku and sees this error:

- install heroku cli
- login via `heroku login`
- `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo`
- `heroku repo:purge_cache -a $YOURAPPNAME`

then do a manual rebuild

Answer (score 2):

Clean the cache and reinstall:

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run these two commands before installing the package:

- `yarn config set unsafe-disable-integrity-migration false`
- `yarn cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

Tried to upgrade yarn and it solved my problem. It may be due to the compatibility issue

```
yarn policies set-version
```

Will download the latest stable release

Reference : yarn docs https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/policies/#toc-policies-set-version